# Как отлавливать на стороне сервера подключения по rtmp

Tags: linux, rtmp

Настроен nginx трансляции сервер получает по протоколу rtmp, статистику я могу посмотреть благодаря stat.xsl , но как мне программно отлавливать новые потоки, что бы с ними работать? 
То есть пошёл новый поток например или закончился поток , как мне получить данные, что бы работать с данными. Скорее всего то, что указано в access.log
00.19.00.72 [25/May/2020:22:05:17 +0300] PUBLISH "live" "2" "" - 21159151 529 "" "FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)" (2m 48s)
или error.log

```
2020/05/25 22:02:28 [info] 16915#0: *84719 client connected '00.19.17.72'
2020/05/25 22:02:28 [info] 16915#0: *84719 connect: app='live' args='' flashver='FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)' swf_url='rtmp://domen.ru/live' tc_url='rtmp://domen.ru/live' page_url='' acodecs=0 vcodecs=0 object_encoding=0, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
2020/05/25 22:02:29 [info] 16915#0: *84719 createStream, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
2020/05/25 22:02:29 [info] 16915#0: *84719 publish: name='2' args='' type=live silent=0, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
2020/05/25 22:05:17 [info] 16915#0: *84719 deleteStream, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
2020/05/25 22:05:17 [info] 16915#0: *84719 disconnect, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
2020/05/25 22:05:17 [info] 16915#0: *84719 deleteStream, client: 00.19.17.72, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
```

Буду благодарен любым мыслям, но если будет код, буду благодарен вдвойне )

Comment: В документации nginx все это есть: [раз](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#exec_push), [два](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_publish)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.